# simple string counter program debugging (pointers)

Tags: c, string, pointers

I am new to C programming and pointers.
I made a simple program where I can read in the string and the program tells you how many characters are there and how many alphabets had appeared how many times.
Somehow, my output is not right. I think it might be my pointer and dereferencing problem.

here is my main:

```
extern int* count (char* str);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int numOfChars =0;
  int numOfUniqueChars = 0;
  char str[80];
  int *counts;

  strcpy(str, argv[1]);
  printf("counting number of characters for \"%s\"..\n", str);
  printf("\n");
 
  counts = count(str);
  
  int j;
  for (j =0; j<sizeof(counts); j++)
  {
    if(counts[j])
      printf("character %c", *str);
      printf("appeared %d times\n", counts[j]);
      numOfChars++;
      numOfUniqueChars++;
  }

  printf("\"%s\" has a total of %d character(s)\n", str, numOfChars);

  printf(wow %d different ascii character(s) much unique so skill\n", numOfUniqueChars);
}
```

and this is my count function:

```
int* count(char* str)
{
  int* asctb = malloc(256);
  int numOfChars =0;
  int i;
  int c;
    for(i = 0; i<strlen(str); i++)
       c = str[i];
       asctb[c]++;

  numOfChars += strlen(str);

  return asctb;
}
```

and when I compile and run it, my result comes up like this:

> ./countingCharacter doge
>
> counting number of characters for "doge"...
>
> appeared 0 times
>
> appeared 0 times
>
> appeared 0 times
>
> appeared 0 times
>
> "doge" has a total of 4 character(s)
>
> wow 4 different ascii character(s) much unique so skill

But, I want my result to be like this:

> Character d appeared 1 times
>
> Character e appeared 1 times
>
> Character g appeared 1 times
>
> Character o appeared 1 times
>
> "doge" has a total of 4 character(s)
>
> wow 4 different ascii character(s) much unique so skill

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

i added curly braces for my for loop in the main function.

now i get this result:

> ./countingCharacter doge
>
> character @ appeared 7912 times
>
> character d appeared 1 times
>
> character e appeared 1 times
>
> character g appeared 1 times
>
> character o appeared 1 times

why do I get that "@" in the beginning??

Comment: It's probably not your only problem but a major problem is that you seem to think that C indentation is used for scoping. That is not the case. So some of your `for` loops and `if` blocks are incorrect as their bodies only contain the next line of code instead of the entire following block of code as you clearly intended. You need to enclose the loop/if body in braces: `for (...) { <loop body> }`

Comment: @kaylum oh thank you very much for the tip! :)

Comment: `for (j =0; j<sizeof(counts); j++)` where `sizeof(counts)` where you have declared `int *counts;` is always `sizeof(int*)`  or `8`

Comment: You *get that* `"@"` *in the beginning* of your code because you are attempting to read an *uninitialized value* from `counts` after it is returned from `count`, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @kaylum said, one particularly large issue is your use of braces. If you don't use braces with a control flow statement (`if`, `for`, `while`, etc.), only the next line is counted as a part of that statement. As such, this segment:

```
if (counts[j])
    printf("character %c", *str);
    printf("appeared %d times\n", counts[j]);
    /* ... */
```

...will only execute the first `printf` if `counts[j] != 0`, but will unconditionally execute the following statements.

Your use of `malloc` is also incorrect. `malloc(256)` will only allocate 256 bytes; one `int` is generally 4 bytes, but this differs based on the compiler and the machine. As such, when `malloc`'ing an array of any type, it's good practice to use the following technique:

```
type *array = malloc(element_count * sizeof(type));
```

In your case, this would be:

```
int *asctb = malloc(256 * sizeof(int));
```

This ensures you have room to count all the possible values of `char`. In addition, you'll have to change the way you iterate through `counts` as `sizeof (counts)` does not accurately represent the size of the array (it will most likely be 4 or 8 depending on your system).

The variable `numOfChars` will not behave the way you expect it to. It looks to me like you're trying to share it between the two functions, but because of the way it's declared this will not happen. In order to give global access to the variable, it needs to be declared at *global scope*, outside of any function.

Also, the line:

```
printf("character %c ", *str);
```

...neither keeps track of what characters you've printed nor which you're supposed to, instead just repeatedly printing the first character. `*str` should be `(char)j`, since you're printing ASCII values.

That ought to do it, I think.

Comment: Thank you very much. You're answer solved all my problems in my program! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to C, there are a number of issues in your code you need to pay attention to. First, if a function returns a value, **validate** that value. Otherwise, from that point in your code on, you can have no confidence that it is actually operating on the value or memory location you think it is. For example, each of the following should be validated (or changed to stay within allowable array bounds):

```
strcpy(str, argv[1]);

int* asctb = malloc(256);

counts = count(str);
```

What if `argv[1]` had `100` chars? What if `malloc` returned `NULL`? How do you know `count` succeeded? Always include the necessary validations needed by your code.

While not an error, the standard coding style for C avoids `caMelCase` variables in favor of all *lower-case*. See e.g. [**NASA - C Style Guide, 1994**](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/dts/pm/Papers/nasa-c-style.pdf) So

```
int numOfChars =0;
int numOfUniqueChars = 0;
```

could simply be `nchars` and `nunique`.

Next, all your `if` and `for` loop syntax fails to encapsulate the required statements in *braces*, e.g. `{...}` to create a proper block for your `if` or `for`. For example, the following:

```
for(i = 0; i<strlen(str); i++)
    c = str[i];
    asctb[c]++;
```

only loops over `c = str[i];` and `asctb[c]++;` is only executed *AFTER* the loop exits.

You must **initialize** your variable, (especially your array elements) **before** you attempt to reference them otherwise *undefined behavior* results. (it could seem to work, give weird output like a strange `"@"` character, or *segfault*, that's why it is undefined). You have a big problem here:

```
int* asctb = malloc(256);
```

None of the values in `asctb` are initialized. So when you return the array to `main()` and loop over all values in the array, every element that was not explicitly assigned a value causes undefined behavior. You can either set all values to `0` with `memset`, or recognize when you need all values initialized and use `calloc` instead:

```
int *asctb = calloc (1, 256);
```

Avoid the use of "*magic-numbers*" in your code. `256` above is a great example. Don't litter you code with these magic-numbers, instead defined a constant for them at the beginning of your code with either `#define` or for numerical constants, use an `enum` instead.

Lastly, in any code your write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 responsibilites regarding any block of memory allocated: **(1)** always preserves a pointer to the starting address for the block of memory so, **(2)** it can be freed using `free` when it is no longer needed. You should validate your memory use by running your code though a *Memory Error Checking Program*, such as `valgrind` on Linux. It's simple to do and will save you from yourself more times than you can imagine.

Putting all these pieces together and fixing additional logic errors in your code, you look like you were attempting something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* constants for max characters in str and values in asctb */
enum { MAXC = 80, MAXTB = 128 };

int *count (char *str);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 2) { /* validate str given as argument 1 */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input, usage: %s str.\n",
                argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    /* initialize all variables avoid CamelCase names in C */
    char str[MAXC] = "";
    int j = 0, nchars = 0, nunique = 0;
    int *counts = NULL;

    strncpy (str, argv[1], MAXC - 1); /* limit copy len   */
    str[MAXC - 1] = 0;  /* nul-terminate str */

    printf ("\ncounting number of characters for \"%s\"..\n\n", str);

    if (!(counts = count (str))) { /* validate return */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: count() returned NULL.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (j = 0; j < MAXTB; j++)
        if (counts[j]) {
            printf ("character '%c' appeared: %d times\n", 
                    (char)j, counts[j]);
            nchars += counts[j];
            nunique++;
        }

    free (counts);  /* free allocated memory */

    printf ("\n\"%s\" has a total of %d character(s)\n", str, nchars);    
    printf (" wow %d different ascii character(s) much unique so skill\n\n",
            nunique);

    return 0;   /* main is a function of type 'int' and returns a value */
}

int *count (char *str)
{
    if (!str) return NULL;  /* validate str */

    int *asctb = calloc (1, sizeof *asctb * MAXTB);
    size_t i;   /* you are comparing with size_t in loop */

    if (!asctb) {   /* validate memory allocation - always */
        fprintf (stderr, "count() error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
        asctb[(int)str[i]]++;   /* array indexes are type 'int' */

    return asctb;
}
```

(*note:* the first `30` characters in `counts` are in the *non-printable* range, see [**ASCIItable.com**](http://www.asciitable.com/). The indexes were left as you had them, but note, in practice you may want to shift them unless you are interested in counting the non-printable `\t`, `\n`, etc. chars).

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/ccount "address 12234"

counting number of characters for "address 12234"..

character ' ' appeared: 1 times
character '1' appeared: 1 times
character '2' appeared: 2 times
character '3' appeared: 1 times
character '4' appeared: 1 times
character 'a' appeared: 1 times
character 'd' appeared: 2 times
character 'e' appeared: 1 times
character 'r' appeared: 1 times
character 's' appeared: 2 times

"address 12234" has a total of 13 character(s)
wow 10 different ascii character(s) much unique so skill
```

Look over the logic and syntax corrections and let me know if you have any further questions.